# Joining 2 different tables where user_id equals to and created_at between 2 dates

Tags: sql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

In my application, I have 3 models `User`, `Visit`, `Post`. What I want to achieve is selecting `visits` & `posts` that belongs to the `user`, where `created_at` is between 2 dates and `group` them by **day** *(I am using `groupdate` for `group_by_day`)* and return a `count` on `visits` & `posts` for that giving day.

I have tried several with no luck:

```
User.joins(:visits,:posts).where("visits.user_id = ?, posts.user_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id)
    .where("visits.created_at >= ? AND visits.created_at <= ?", 15.days.ago.midnight.in_time_zone("Berlin"), 2.days.ago.midnight.in_time_zone("Berlin"))
    .where("posts.created_at >= ? AND posts.created_at <= ?", 15.days.ago.midnight.in_time_zone("Berlin"), 2.days.ago.midnight.in_time_zone("Berlin"))
    .group_by_day(:created_at, range: 15.days.ago.midnight.in_time_zone("Berlin")..Time.now.in_time_zone("Berlin"), format: "%d %b")
    .count
```

*This gave me: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid`*

```
SQLite3::SQLException: row value misused: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 UTC', "users"."created_at") AS strftime_y_m_d_00_00_00_utc_users_created_at FROM "users" INNER JOIN "visits" ON "visits"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (visits.user_id = 1, posts.user_id = 1) AND (visits.created_at >= '2020-01-20 00:00:00' AND visits.created_at <= '2020-02-02 00:00:00') AND (posts.created_at >= '2020-01-20 00:00:00' AND posts.created_at <= '2020-02-02 00:00:00') AND ("users"."created_at" >= '2020-01-20 00:00:00' AND "users"."created_at" <= '2020-02-04 19:03:28.383850') GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 UTC', "users"."created_at")
```

*My Models:*

```
class Visit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :visits
  has_many :posts
end
```

I've been looking around and tried a few different ways with no luck. 
Any rails help just *plain* `sql` or tip is much appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one :**

```
_start_time = 15.days.ago.midnight.in_time_zone("Berlin") ## get start time
_end_time = 2.days.ago.midnight.in_time_zone("Berlin") ## get end time

 #### query ###
User.joins(:visits, :posts).where(visits: { created_at: (_start_time.._end_time) }).where(posts: { created_at: (_start_time.._end_time) }).group_by_day(:created_at, range: _start_time..Time.now.in_time_zone("Berlin"), format: "%d %b").count
```

Comment: Thanks @prakash. `sql` output is `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 UTC', "users"."created_at") AS strftime_y_m_d_00_00_00_utc_users_created_at FROM "users" INNER JOIN "visits" ON "visits"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "visits"."created_at" BETWEEN ? AND ? AND "posts"."created_at" BETWEEN ? AND ? AND ("users"."created_at" >= '2020-01-21 00:00:00' AND "users"."created_at" <= '2020-02-05 18:55:01.042324') GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 UTC', "users"."created_at")` and it took **719639.1ms** and wrong output :/

Comment: @Rubioli in your query you are using created_at on both table to filter data and looks like you don't have any index on it that's why the query is taking so long to get output. Please share what output are you expecting with more details.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I added index to `created_at` and still really slow. What I'm looking is to get the **user's** `visits` & `post` **group by day**